# Azure Devops Condition Build Validation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a condition that checks in Build validation Was there a change in a particular folder?
I have a JOB that is targeted to a specific folder and I want in build validation it will not run this Job if there was no change in the files in the folder.

And when they do Merge I want them to run even if there was no change. (They will run normally as if there are no conditions)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried triggers and path settings in yaml.
`# specific path build trigger: branches: include: - master - releases/* paths: include: - docs exclude: - docs/README.md`
Refer the link:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers
Based on those paths in the above setting you can trigger the pipeline.
Same syntax can be used for Pull request trigger also. Specify your folder in the path.